# Why does running Cypress on a React/GraphQL app return network errors when normal browsing doesn't?

Tags: graphql, cypress, grandstack

I have a React/apollo client and an apollo/neo4j backend application based on GRANDStack. 
My React app runs on localhost:3000 and my GraphQL on localhost:4001/graphql, and they communicate without fail. All is working well in the app (with CORS enabled), but I wanted to implement testing with Cypress.

Should I expect Cypress to be able to observe the flow between React and GraphQL without error? Or is this beyond its capability?

**What I've tried:**
I set up Cypress and ran the following test:

```
it("Opens myPlan.", function() {
    cy.visit("localhost:3000/myPlan");
    cy.wait(6000);
});
```

At first cypress setup, my site loaded. One of the first things that the app does is graphql query a few values, and create a dropdown box based on those values. While this and all other graphql requests work fine in the browser, I get `"{"graphQLErrors":[],"networkError":{"name":"ServerParseError","response":{},"statusCode":404,"bodyText":""},"message":"Network error: Unexpected end of JSON input"}"` errors in cypress for the same code.

Presumably, the problem was because there are 2 endpoints, and cy.visit only allows one. I tried disabled ChromeWebSecurity and tried an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin-master" plugin.

**Edit:** I found someone that knew Cypress, and they suggested adding:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4001/",
```

to my react client config. This avoids the multi-port issues, and Cypress works.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: Hmm, to be fair, this is not a question primarily about code, but about capabilities of Cypress handling a site over 2 ports. Maybe I could reword it in that way.
A minimally reproduce-able config of GRANDstack would be pages and pages of code, but that gives me the idea to test this on a vanilla GRANDstack template and work backwards.

Comment: Do not put "Solved" in the title. Answers should not be part of the question. Instead, put the solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I found someone that knew Cypress, and they suggested adding:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:4001/",
```

to my react client config. This avoids the multi-port issues, and Cypress works.